# Adding a next button to pagination javascript

Tags: jquery, html, pagination

Using this js pagination I would like to get some help on how to add a next and previous button to it. Also I have been trying really hard to make it so that the OL is dynamic and has as many pages as there is content. Some help would be very much appreciated. [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/184/).

```
 pageSize = 3;

 showPage = function(page) {
 $(".content").hide();
 $(".content").each(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
        $(this).show();
});        
}

showPage(1);

<div class="content">1 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">2 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">3 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">4 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">5 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">6 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">7 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">8 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">9 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">10 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">11 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">12 I have some content</div>

<ol id="pagin">
        <li><a class="current" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, here is my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/405/
Everything that you required is there. It evens continues further if you had more div, it is dynamic.

I hopes it helps you

**JS:**

```
pageSize = 3;
var i = 1;
showPage = function(page) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content").each(function(n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
            $(this).show();
    });        
}

showPage(i);

$("#previous").click(function() {
    $("#next").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    if (i != 1) {
      showPage(--i);
    }
});
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#previous").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    if (i < ($('.content').length)/3) {
      showPage(++i);
    }    
});
```

A bit of **HTML** modification:

```
<ol id="pagin">
            <li><a id='previous' class="current" href="#">Previous</a></li>
            <li><a id='next' href="#">Next</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: oh this works great, If I wanted to add some page numbers between them would I be able to work off this or would it be a different approach?

Comment: It is compatible ! There's only a few lines to add.
You got the `i` variable on your disposal, which refers to the current page. You can add some `<li>` and set the numbers of the page on them dynamically depending on the `i` variable, updating the number of the new `<li>` during the `$("#previous").click` òr `$("#next").click` listener ;)

Comment: ok cool! im going to start working it out thanks for the help!

Comment: should I create a loop to display the page numbers and append new <li> to page after the previous?

Comment: I don't understand you sry, but what you should do instead is to create 3 <li>, with three differents id, and in each 'click' function, you change those <li>'s content to what you wish, thanks to the i variable

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/184/

```
$('a.prev, a.next').click(function(){
    var a = $(this),
        current = $('#pagin li a.current'),
        page = parseInt(current.text());
    if (a.hasClass('prev')) {
        page--;
        if (page < 1) page = 1;
    } else if (a.hasClass('next')) {
        page++;
        if (page > pageCount) page = pageCount;
    }
    $('.page:eq(' + (page - 1) + ')').click();
});
```